# How to create 2 different audio streams that appear alternately on a video with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming

I know about the interplay of 2 videos with the command "enable = 'lt (mod (t"). But I don't know how to make two audio streams intertwine appear in the same video. Can you show me if there is one? I have a picture (attached).[image]

In the example above I have 1 video and 2 audio streams. Audio 1 and audio 2 appear in the video every 20 seconds and 30 seconds until the video ends.

Comment: Are Audio 1 and Audio 2 30/20 second clips that you want to repeat over and over, or do you have two audio clips Audio 1 and Audio 2 the same length as your video that you want to cut between every 30/20 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the `concat` input format: Create a file called `audio.ffconcat` besides your two audio files, containing

```
file "audio1.mp3"
file "audio2.mp3"
file "audio1.mp3"
file "audio2.mp3"
...
```

This should be long enough (enough lines) to make sure the total length is long enough, but it won't hurt if it is too long.

Now use

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -f concat -i audio.ffconcat -map 0:v -map 1:a -shortest ....
```

To create the output

Comment: Is there any way I can change parameters if needed. I want the audio section attached to the video.

Comment: @NguyễnVănThân I don't understand your comment. What parameters do you want to change? Ideally edit your question and include the full, uncut command line output from what you've already tried (with the video).

Comment: The `...` in my command is where you put all the "normal" parameters

Comment: No need to list files multiple times. List them once and stream_loop the concat.

Comment: @Gyan Yes and no. There are many, many older versions of FFmpeg out there, which do not yet have the loop features, So since it is so easy I tend to recommend doing it manually.